# Core data image download only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, download

I have a core data model where I need to download a full res image from our server.

ATM it stores a thumbnail image. When the full screen image is opened the thumbnail version is shown and this triggers the full res download.

However, because the download takes time if you go out of the full screen image and back again before it completes the download then it will start a second download of the same image.

I can think of a few ways of doing this but they all are bit hacky.

Can anyone advise how to go about this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've already tried the tried and tested way of setting a flag to indicate the download is in progress.

Alternatively - store a UUID related to the full scale image and use that as the token in a dispatch_once() call that downloads the image.

Comment: I was going to add a flag to the entity it just seemed hacky. Not sure why. I like the dispatch_once() idea though. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. dispatch_once() is not just for singleton initialisation :) I've used it to display a login screen for an app at startup. Saves messing about with setting and checking a flag in the root view controller.